# LDAP: ldap_rename параметры функции

Tags: php, ldap

помогите пожалуйста примером у кого есть, какие параметры требует функция php ldap_rename(), не совсем понимаю что она требует, глядя на документацию тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ldap-rename.php и на комментарии в ней.

Какое бы значение не подставлял, пишет Invalid DN Syntax.

Необходимо с помощью этой функции (как я понимаю она для этого и создана) перенести пользователя из одной ветки в другую, к примеру из 
ou=people,ou=Department,ou=Org,o=main в ou=deleted,ou=Department,ou=Org,o=main при увольнении работника.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы не полностью указываете DN. Проверьте, с чего у вас в ldap-е начинается корень. Обычно что-то типа dc=domain,dc=com.

Comment: у меня корень cn=root,o=main, я указывал по всякому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример.

```
<?php

$ldaprdn  = 'cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=loc';
$ldappass = 'Pa$$word';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.128.217.122")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if($ldapconn)
{
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
    $old_dn = 'cn=Василий Пушкин,l=Брест,o=Аутсорсинг,ou=Personnel,dc=domain,dc=loc';
    $new_rdn = 'cn=Василий Пушкин';
    $new_parent = 'l=Минск,o=Аутсорсинг,ou=Personnel,dc=domain,dc=loc';
    ldap_rename($ldapconn, $old_dn, $new_rdn, $new_parent, TRUE);

    ldap_close($ldapconn); 
}

?>
```

RDN `l=Минск,o=Аутсорсинг,ou=Personnel,dc=domain,dc=loc` должен существовать в структуре LDAP-а **до переноса объекта**!

Переносит объект

```
dc=domain,dc=loc
       |__ou=Personnel
               |__o=Аутсорсинг
                     |__l=Брест
                          |__ cn=Василий Пушкин
```

в новое место

```
dc=domain,dc=loc
       |__ou=Personnel
               |__o=Аутсорсинг
                     |__l=Минск
                          |__ cn=Василий Пушкин
```

Где `dc=domain,dc=loc` - "корень" LDAP сервера.

Из [мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ldap-rename.php):

> Замечание:
>
> Эта функция в настоящее время работает только с LDAPv3. Возможно, вам
>   придется использовать ldap_set_option() перед привязкой, используя
>   LDAPv3. Эта функция доступна только при использовании OpenLDAP 2.xx
>   или Netscape Directory SDK x.x.

Поскольку тестировалось на OpenLDAP 2.хх, то работает. В других случаях возможно придется пользоваться [ldap_mod_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ldap-mod-replace.php)

Comment: Спасибо! Уже получилось! Помогли подсказки-советы-примеры, каким-то образом всё до кучи сделало решение моей задачи))

Comment: Ок! Пожалуйста!   )

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение! У меня заработало, т.к. в интернете почти нету примеров по этой функции, может кому в будущем пригодиться. Примеры для того, чтобы дойти до своего решения нашёл тут: https://hotexamples.com/ru/examples/-/-/ldap_rename/php-ldap_rename-function-examples.html

Моё решение было в виде:

- в $dn вставил значение полного dn до объекта (начиная , который я хотел перенести, у меня это было `'uid=username,ou=people,ou=Department,ou=Org,o=main'`)
- отрезал от этого dn uid=login, для того, чтобы перенести с таким же логином пользователя (это будет по функции $newrdn, в виде `'uid=username'`)
- в $parent вставил значение dn до места, куда я хочу вставить запись, в моём случае это было `'ou=people,ou=Department,ou=Org,o=main'`

функция имела вид: 
`ldap_rename($ds, $dn, $newrdn, $parent, true);`

отрезал и сохранял кусочки dn так:

```
$parent = explode(',', $dn);
$newrdn = array_shift($parent);
$parent = join(',', $parent);
```

действительно была ошибка что я вписывал полные dn, начиная от самого корня, а это было не необходимо и функция работает с кусочками dn'a, разделяя 2-м и 3-м параметрами результирующий dn.

*записал в том числе и для себя, если вдруг в будущем забуду и придётся вновь столкнуться с ldap.*